# Joining two large tables in mysql giving server time out

Tags: mysql, sql

This query is inefficient and unable to execute. track and desiredspeed  table have almost million records.... after this we want to self join the track table for further processing. any efficient approach to execute bellow query is appreciated..

```
select 
      t_id,
      route_id,
      t.timestamp,
      s_lat,
      s_long,
      longitude,
      latitude,
      SQRT(POW((latitude - d_lat),2) + POW((longitude - d_long),2)) as dst, 
      SUM(speed*18/5)/count(*) as speed,
      '20' as actual_speed,
      ((20-(speed*18/5))/(speed*18/5))*100 as speed_variation 
   from 
      track t,
      desiredspeed s 
   WHERE 
          LEFT(s_lat,6) = LEFT(latitude,6) 
      AND LEFT(s_long,6)=LEFT(longitude,6) 
      AND t_id > 53445 
   group by 
      route_id,
      s_lat,
      s_long 
   order by 
      t_id asc
```

Comment: Please format the code so it's not all in one line.

Comment: Can you share the tables structures (including indexes and constraints)?

Comment: sorry I can't give tables because of limited reputations. There are two table: track and desiredspeed with columns as specified above. Please mention if you want any specific information on table structure

Comment: You're doing a theta-style join. That's **extremely inefficient**. Start by changing that to an ANSI JOIN. Theta join is `from track t, desiredspeed s` while ANSI JOIN is when you define which keys to join on, using *something like*`INNER JOIN desiredspeed s ON s.fkey = t.pkey`. After that, make sure you don't fetch millions of rows. And if you do, at least ensure you've got sufficient memory for such things.

Answer (score 0):

- firstly you are using sybase join syntax i would change that
- you are also performing two computations per join across large datasets this is likely to be inefficient
- this will not be able to use an index as you are performing computation on the column, either store the data precomputed or alternately add a computed column based on the rule applied above, and index accordingly
- Finally it may be quicker if you used temp tables or common Table expressions (although do not know MySQL too well here)

Comment: How to use temp table or common table expression?